# Why is My answer Wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a question here $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{8}{e^{1-4x}}\right)$

I simplify this  $8\left(\frac{1}{\left(e^{1-4x}\right)^2}\right)\left(-4e^{1-4x}\right)$ to  $\left(\frac{32}{e^{1-4x}}\right)$

but I am being told this is wrong am I missing out a step ?

Comment: Your answer is correct, although it could be made neater. Observe that $-(1-4x) = 4x-1$ so the exponent can be moved up from under the denominator making the answer easier to look at.

Comment: @JónÁskellÞorbjarnarson Thank you

Comment: There's a $-$ missing since $(1/x)'=-1/x^2$.

Comment: Yep. A $-$ is missing...

Answer (score 0):

What I was failing to observe was that I could write $32e^{4x-1}$ instead of $\left(\frac{32}{\left(e^{1-4x}\right)}\right)$